# Modify protected value with structure

Tags: c++, class, struct, virtual, vtable

I've got a class:

```
class Fruit
{
protected:
    int Vitamins
    [...]
public:
    [...]
}
```

a structure:

```
struct InTheMatrixFruit
{
  int           vitamins;
  virtual       ~InTheMatrixFruit();
};
```

and a function which takes a reference on Fruit:

```
void function(Fruit &fruit);
```

in this function if I write:

```
reinterpret_cast<InTheMatrixFruit&>(fruit).vitamins = 300;
```

It does modify the vitamins protected value.

But, If I remove the virtual like this:

```
struct InTheMatrixFruit
    {
      int           vitamins;
      ~InTheMatrixFruit();
    };
```

It doesn't work anymore.

Why it works with virtual and not without ?

I'm thinking about the VTables.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can't do that, `Fruit` and `InTheMatrixFruit` are completely unrelated classes. Don't use `reinterpret_cast<>` unless you're 100% sure what you're doing!!

Comment: You're asking for trouble doing this. If someone adds a new member variable to either class before the definition of `vitamins` then your code is going to fail.

Comment: As said in microsoft site (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0w9f63b.aspx): "The result of a reinterpret_cast cannot safely be used for anything other than being cast back to its original type. Other uses are, at best, nonportable"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declaration of `Fruit` probably contains at least a virtual function.

In common implementations of virtual functions a virtual table is used. A pointer to the virtual table is stored as the *first* element in the memory representation of your object. It doesn't matter where you declare a virtual function, the virtual table will always be at the beginning.

So by declaring a virtual function in `InTheMatrixFruit` you create a "padding" *before* the `int vitamins` so it matches with the `vitamins` of `Fruit`.

Answer (score 4):

Because the size of the class instance changes and, with it, the offset to the `vitamins` member. This is beacuse a `virtual` function will cause a vtable pointer to be stored inside the instance before the memory allocated to the member, as you guessed.

Beware! `reinterpret_cast` could kill your kittens!